# Precision/recall curve and accuracy/threshold interpretation

Tags: r, logistic, predictive-models

I am running a logisitc regression and trying to interpret the predictive power it generates. How should I interpret the precision/recall curve and the accuracy as a function of threshold?

My precision/recall curve looks very strange with the immediate dip.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the left end of your precision/recall curve, you classify *everything* as "negative". So you have $TP=FP=0$. No matter how many true positives $P$ you have (assuming $P>0$), your recall is

$$ \frac{TP}{P}=\frac{0}{P}=0. $$

On the other hand, your precision is

$$ \frac{TP}{TP+FP}=\frac{0}{0+0}=\frac{0}{0}, $$

which is undefined, but your software may simply set it to (or plot it as) one.

Very much related: [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352) and [Classification probability threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352). So, in reply to your question "How should I interpret the precision/recall curve and the accuracy as a function of threshold?", my answer would be "don't".